# Time cost of iterating from the outsides in

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a very basic question, but here goes:

If I have an array, and I have a pointer on i1 = 0 and another one at i2 = array.length - 1-- and the code looks something like this:

```
until i1 >= i2
  #search the array between indices i1 to i2 (inclusive)
  i1 += 1 
  i2 -= 1 
end
```

What is the time complexity here? I know that N elements get touched, then N-2 elements get touched, then N-4.. etc. So the time complexity is the summation of N + (N-2) + (N-4).... etc correct? If so, what is the result of this summation in big O notation?

Comment: I think the algorithm is still actually `O(N^2)`.  It iterate roughly `N/2` times.

Comment: What is `#search the array between indices i1 to i2 (inclusive)` are you recursively calling itself again?

Comment: Correct. `N + (N-2) + (N-4)...` form an arithmetic progression. Find a number of elements in this sequence. Then use a formula to calculate the sum of the first `K` elements of the sequence.

Comment: @bureaquete I mean I'm iterating through all the elements in between them. Essentially left the comment there to show that each element in between i1 and i2 is being touched once per iteration.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you do multiple iterations of the same values in the middle again & again? In the first step of `i1 = 0` and `i2 = length-1` should be enough to check all values, wouldn't it be better to call function recursively then you'd have O(n), currently you have O(n^2)